# Hibernate: How to join two tables with one of it doesn't have an id?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, join

My two tables (in SQL Server):

```
create table cluster (
    id bigint primary key identity(1,1),
    name varchar(100)
)

create table cluster_member (
    cluster_id bigint,
    member_name varchar(100)
)
```

The table cluster_member doesn't have an id. The column cluster_id is like a foreign key, reference to the id column in cluster table.

I used Hiberate Tools to generate 2 @Entity classes and a @Embeddable class. I added some class variables and @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations trying to join the two tables. But I got an error saying:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_hk6sas3oycvcljwbjar7p9ky3:cluster_member [cluster_id,member_name])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (cluster [id])
```

The error message is pretty clear. But I don't know how to fix it. Please help.

Here is my code:

**Cluster.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cluster" )
public class Cluster implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<ClusterMember> members;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
            return this.id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", length = 100)
    public String getName() {
            return this.name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
    public Set<ClusterMember> getMembers() {
            return members;
    }
}
```

**ClusterMember.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cluster_member" )
public class ClusterMember implements java.io.Serializable {

    private ClusterMemberId id;
    private Cluster cluster;

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "clusterId", column = @Column(name = "cluster_id")),
                    @AttributeOverride(name = "memberName", column = @Column(name = "member_name", length = 100)) })
    public ClusterMemberId getId() {
            return this.id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cluster_id")
    public Cluster getCluster() {
            return cluster;
    }
}
```

**ClusterMemberId.java**:

```
@Embeddable
public class ClusterMemberId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long clusterId;
    private String memberName;

    @Column(name = "cluster_id")
    public Long getClusterId() {
            return this.clusterId;
    }

    @Column(name = "member_name", length = 100)
    public String getMemberName() {
            return this.memberName;
    }
}
```

**main function**:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria("my.hibernate.table.Cluster");
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", "%ABC%"));
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Cluster> clusters = criteria.list();
            for (Cluster cluster: clusters) {
                    System.out.println(cluster.toString());
            }
            tx.commit();
            sessionFactory.close();
    }
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
             <mapping class="my.hibernate.table.Cluster" />
             <mapping class="my.hibernate.table.ClusterMember" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
public Set<ClusterMember> getMembers() {
        return members;
}
```

to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cluster")
public Set<ClusterMember> getMembers() {
        return members;
}
```

and add insertable/updatable to false on the associated ManyToOne mapping.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cluster_id", insertable="false", updatable="false")
public Cluster getCluster() {
        return cluster;
}
```

Because you are not really interested in the ClusterMember.id but in the FK linking back to Cluster.

In Hibernate you cannot use the same column in to different mapping. The "ClusterMember" already uses "cluster_id" for the @Id property, hence if you plan on using for a ManyToOne association, you need to instruct Hibernate to ignore any changes to this end (inserts and updates should be ignored).

Also you can use [Hibernate's @MapsId annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e2338), for composite identifiers with alternate associated mappings.

Comment: Now I get a different error: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: ClusterMember column: cluster_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: I edited my post. Added main function, and my hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: Updated my response too.

Comment: That worked! One little change is: it should be insertable=false, updatable=false. Thank you so much!